# Reactor retry not calling method to be retried

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a method that always returns `Mono.error`

```
private Mono<String> doSomething() {
        System.out.println("doSomething");
        return Mono.error(new Error());
}
```

I tried to retry the execution 3 times

```
Mono<String> mono =
                myClass.doSomething()
                        .doOnSubscribe(x -> System.out.println("Subscribe"))
                        .retryWhen(companion -> companion
                                .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println(s + " at " + LocalTime.now()))
                                .zipWith(Flux.range(1, 4), (error, index) -> {
                                    if (index < 4) return index;
                                    else throw Exceptions.propagate(error);
                                })
                                .flatMap(index -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(index * 100)))
                                .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("retried at " + LocalTime.now()))
                        );

        mono.block();
```

However, `doSomething` is only printed once, while `Subscribe` printed 4 times (1 x at the beginning, 3 x retries)

How can it re-subscribe without execute the method?

What I want to do is execute `doSomething` at every retry

Answer (score 6):

To execute `doSomething` at every retry, you can use [`defer`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-) operator in combination with [`retryWhen`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retryWhen-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Mono.defer(() -> myClass.doSomething()
                        .doOnSubscribe(x -> System.out.println("Subscribe")))
    .retryWhen(// rest of the code
```

Basically, the [`retryWhen`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retryWhen-java.util.function.Function-) operator **works by re-subscribing** to the `Mono` source, and the [`defer`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-) operator **re-evaluates the lambda each time there is a new subscribe**. So, at the end you get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`doSomething()` is only ever *called* once - that is, explicitly by you to retrieve the error based `Mono`. The `Mono` that's returned is indeed subscribed to again on each retry, but the method that originally returned it isn't called again.

The preferable thing to do here would be to refactor your code so that any side effects happen on subscribing to the `Mono`, eg:

```
private Mono<String> doSomething() {
    return Mono.<String>error(new Error()).doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("doSomething"));
}
```

However, if that's not possible, then you can cause `doSomething()` to be executed as-is on each retry by using it as a supplier and flattening the result. If you want to go down that route, then replace:

```
myClass.doSomething()
```

...with:

```
Mono.fromSupplier(myClass::doSomething).flatMap(p->p)
```